# HP ENVY - 13-ad001la Pop-Os 19.10 PCI Card reader not working

Tags: linux, drivers, sd-card, pci

I have an HP Envy 13-ad001la with PopOs 19.10. The card reader is not working; when I use `lspci` I get this is an Alcor Micro device reader:

```
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Alcor Micro Device 6625
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 834a
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at a1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [80] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Latency Tolerance Reporting
```

To my understanding, "Unassigned class" means that Linux can't find a driver for this device.
I searched for the corresponding driver and found that the driver was "alcor_pci" (https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/MISC_ALCOR_PCI.html) and it wasn't loaded, so I used modprobe to load it.

```
 ~  lsmod | grep alcor     
alcor_pci              20480  0
```

But after this it's still not working, `lshw` is showing the following (NO RECLAMADO means UNCLAIMED):

```
*-pci:0
             descripción: PCI bridge
             producto: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
             fabricante: Intel Corporation
             id físico: 1c
             información del bus: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             versión: f1
             anchura: 32 bits
             reloj: 33MHz
             capacidades: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuración: driver=pcieport
             recursos: irq:122 memoria:a1200000-a12fffff
           *-generic NO RECLAMADO
                descripción: Unassigned class
                producto: Alcor Micro
                fabricante: Alcor Micro
                id físico: 0
                información del bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
                versión: 00
                anchura: 64 bits
                reloj: 33MHz
                capacidades: cap_list
                configuración: latency=0
                recursos: memoria:a1200000-a1200fff
```

Can anybody help me, please? I don't know if I need to do anything else after loading the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot work, because the AU6625 device ID was only added in [linux 5.6](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/444972b2b268c3272d39105bdc8d1266177f5d42).

([some drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442833/forcing-driver-to-device-match) do support "force using" modules even with a mismatch, but I really wouldn't hold my breath for card readers to support that)

Answer (score 0):

( This text is an automatic translation from French to English.)

Hello,
my experience with this card.:

```
*"Alcor Micro AU6625 PCI-E Flash card reader controller"*
```

if you are willing to recompile your linux kernel, the card seems to work very well with the AU6621 driver already included in the kernel (since kernel version 5.5.6 ).
Just "rename" it in the source code of the module and then recompile the linux kernel.
This works for me since kernel version 5.5.9.
I've been using it for a few months now without (apparent) problems, with these kernels version ( 5.5.9, 5.5.16,  5.6.7, 5.6.9)

my environment:

```
"HP ENVY Laptop 13-ad1xx"
LSPCI
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Alcor Micro AU6625 PCI-E Flash card reader controller
Debian
Stock linux kernel: https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.6.7.tar.xz
```

Warning, I am not a developer, I am just a sysadmin who likes to recompile his linux kernel from time to time.

The rest of this post assumes you already know how to recompile a linux kernel. Otherwise it's better not to continue this process;
Building a kernel wrong and running it can be very dangerous, you could corrupt all the data on your hard drive.

Once the sources are extracted, the following files need to be adjusted
 (found by shell command   "$ grep -i -n -r "AU662"   *" ) at the root of the decompressed kernel sources.

Change all references with "6621" to "6625".

Before change:
$ grep -i -r -n "AU662" *

```
*drivers/misc/cardreader/alcor_pci.c:5: * Driver for Alcor Micro AU6601 and AU6621 controllers*
*drivers/misc/cardreader/alcor_pci.c:37:static const struct alcor_dev_cfg au6621_cfg = {*
*drivers/misc/cardreader/alcor_pci.c:41:static const struct alcor_dev_cfg au6625_cfg = {*
*drivers/misc/cardreader/alcor_pci.c:48:    { PCI_DEVICE(PCI_ID_ALCOR_MICRO, PCI_ID_AU6621),*
*drivers/misc/cardreader/alcor_pci.c:49:        .driver_data = (kernel_ulong_t)&au6621_cfg },*
*drivers/misc/cardreader/alcor_pci.c:50:    { PCI_DEVICE(PCI_ID_ALCOR_MICRO, PCI_ID_AU6625),*
*drivers/misc/cardreader/alcor_pci.c:51:        .driver_data = (kernel_ulong_t)&au6625_cfg },*
*drivers/misc/cardreader/Kconfig:8:   au6621.*
*drivers/mmc/host/alcor.c:5: * Driver for Alcor Micro AU6601 and AU6621 controllers*
*drivers/mmc/host/alcor.c:892:      /* The clk will not work on au6621. We need to trigger data*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:5: * Driver for Alcor Micro AU6601 and AU6621 controllers*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:19:#define PCI_ID_AU6621             0x6621*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:20:#define PCI_ID_AU6625             0x6625*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:36: * 0x10 - ADMA phy address. AU6621 only?*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:45: * The au6601 and au6621 have different DMA engines with different issues. One*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:46: * For example au6621 engine is triggered by addr change. No other interaction*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:54:#define AU6621_DMA_PAGE_CNT           0x05*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:57:/* ADMA ctrl? AU6621 only. */*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:58:#define AU6621_DMA_CTRL               0x0c*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:59:#define AU6621_DMA_ENABLE         BIT(0)*
```

After Change:

```
*drivers/misc/cardreader/alcor_pci.c:5: * Driver for Alcor Micro AU6601 and AU6625 controllers*
*drivers/misc/cardreader/alcor_pci.c:37:static const struct alcor_dev_cfg au6625_cfg = {*
*drivers/misc/cardreader/alcor_pci.c:41:/*static const struct alcor_dev_cfg au6625_cfg = {*
*drivers/misc/cardreader/alcor_pci.c:48:    { PCI_DEVICE(PCI_ID_ALCOR_MICRO, PCI_ID_AU6625),*
*drivers/misc/cardreader/alcor_pci.c:49:        .driver_data = (kernel_ulong_t)&au6625_cfg },*
*drivers/misc/cardreader/Kconfig:8:   au6625.*
*drivers/mmc/host/alcor.c:5: * Driver for Alcor Micro AU6601 and AU6625 controllers*
*drivers/mmc/host/alcor.c:892:      /* The clk will not work on au6625. We need to trigger data*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:5: * Driver for Alcor Micro AU6601 and AU6625 controllers*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:19:#define PCI_ID_AU6621             0x6621*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:20:#define PCI_ID_AU6625             0x6625*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:36: * 0x10 - ADMA phy address. AU6625 only?*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:45: * The au6601 and au6625 have different DMA engines with different issues. One*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:46: * For example au6625 engine is triggered by addr change. No other interaction*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:54:#define AU6625_DMA_PAGE_CNT           0x05*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:57:/* ADMA ctrl? AU6625 only. */*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:58:#define AU6625_DMA_CTRL               0x0c*
*include/linux/alcor_pci.h:59:#define AU6625_DMA_ENABLE         BIT(0)*
```

Two Important notes:

- since kernel 5.6.x there seems to be a start of the AU6625 driver included in the kernel, but this included driver doesn't seem to work yet
  (at least on my configuration and up to the 5.6.9 kernel I'm currently using)
  You must therefore "comment" or delete this new part from the code.
- After rebooting on this new compiled kernel, the "lspci" command will continue to display "Unassigned Class ...".
  for me

  02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Alcor Micro AU6625 PCI-E Flash card reader controller

But the card works very well anyway, and is mounted in my Filemanager (Nautilus) like any other.

## dmesg

```
May 10 13:35:35 MylapX kernel: [    0.818161] pci 0000:02:00.0: [1aea:6625] type 00 class 0xff0000
May 10 13:35:35 MylapX kernel: [    0.818209] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xb4200000-0xb4200fff 64bit]
May 10 13:35:35 MylapX kernel: [    0.818386] pci 0000:02:00.0: supports D1 D2
May 10 13:35:35 MylapX kernel: [    0.818388] pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D1 D2 D3hot D3cold

May 10 13:35:35 MylapX kernel: [    2.845290] alcor_pci 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)

May 10 13:35:39 MylapX kernel: [    7.617586] mmc0: Skipping voltage switch
May 10 13:35:39 MylapX kernel: [    7.877031] mmc0: new high speed SDXC card at address aaaa
May 10 13:35:39 MylapX kernel: [    7.880661] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa ACLCF 119 GiB 
May 10 13:35:39 MylapX kernel: [    7.896324]  mmcblk0: p1
```

## fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 119.9 GiB, 127865454592 bytes, 249737216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device         Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1      32768 249737215 249704448 119.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

$ df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk0p1  120G   98G   22G  82% /media/user/3561-6331
```